# Generic way to pass parameters to pthread_create (with variadic template function with 2 packed-parameters lists)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pthreads, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a `thread` class as the C++11 standard defines, by myself, as I found in this a good way to work with variadic templates and other advanced features of the C++ language.

As far as I know, when using the **pthreads** library, when creating a thread, the function assigned to it must have the following signature: `void* method(void* param)`.

The fourth argument of `pthread_create` allows to pass only one parameter.
Searching on the Internet, the most common way to pass more than one parameter is to pack them in a structure and pass a pointer on that structure as a parameter.

Because the C++ `thread` class allows functions with as much parameters as we want, I took a look to the LLVM implementation (surely close to the other ones) and saw they used a **proxy function**, which seems to be the best way for me.

As I don't want to use `forward` or `decay` (the way it's made for LLVM) if possible and make it different, and because copy/paste don't make me learn anything, I though I could have used a variadic templated function as a proxy.

Here's what I've figured out:

```
/** THREAD CLASS **/
template <typename _ret_type, typename... _args_types>
void*
__thread_proxy(void* p)
{
    _ret_type(*fn)(_args_types...) = reinterpret_cast<_ret_type(*)(_args_types...)>(p);
    std::cout << "Thread " << pthread_self() << " speaking! :)" << std::endl;
    fn(6, 'a');
    return bk::null_pointer;
}

class thread
{
    pthread_t _tid;

public:
    thread() :
    _tid(0)
    { }

    template <typename ret_type, typename... args_types>
    thread(ret_type(*fn)(args_types...), args_types... args)
    {
        pthread_create(&_tid, 0, __thread_proxy<ret_type, args_types...>, &fn);
    }
}

/** USAGE **/
void
test(int i, char c)
{
    std::cout << "test: ";
    while (i > 0) {
        std::cout << c;
        i--;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    thread t(test, 6, 'a');
}
```

As you can see, I've been unable to pass the parameters at this time, that's why in the `__thread_proxy` function, I called fn with the parameters directly.
I've used the fourth parameter of `pthread_create` to pass the entry point of the thread. Because the entry point return type and arguments types are passed as template parameters, I though I could have done the same for the parameters.

I've then modified the proxy code to this:

```
template <typename _ret_type, typename... _args_types, _args_types... args_values>
void*
__thread_proxy(void* p)
{
    _ret_type(*fn)(_args_types...) = reinterpret_cast<_ret_type(*)(_args_types...)>(p);
    std::cout << "Thread " << pthread_self() << " speaking! :)" << std::endl;
    fn(args_values...);
    return bk::null_pointer;
}
```

The problem here is that even trying to call the proxy like this `__thread_proxy<ret_type, args_types..., args...>(&fn)` (from the second constructor of thread) returns me the following error:

> > No matching function for call to '__thread_proxy'
> >     Candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter '_args_types'

I've never seen this kind of message but trying to resolve it by myself for at least 4 hours, I think the problem is that when expending the parameters packs, the template parameters are `__thread_proxy<void, int, char, 6, 'a'>`. Seeing this I think I can say that the compiler is unable to know where `_args_types` ends and where `args_values` begins.

I'm counting on your lights guys. I'm not new to templates but I'm not very common with it so every resource you get me to, tips you can give me are welcome.
— Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have two parameter packs in a function template unless one is deduced (i.e. you cannot explicitly provide the arguments for more than one parameter pack). One solution is to copy the arguments in a TLS or on the heap, and pass that as a pointer to the proxy function.

Comment: An additional problem you'll run into is that if you cannot pass function arguments (= run-time values) as template arguments (= compile-time values).

Comment: *"As I don't want to use `forward` or `decay`*" Why? *"and make it different"* How / why?

Comment: I don't know `forward` and `decay`, that's why I want to avoid them if possible as I didn't wanted an additional difficulty.I totally forgot about template args that must be constants, my bad.

Comment: Best you can do is probably using a `std::tuple` for passing those parameters, the first value being the function which shall be called.

Comment: `pthread_create(&_tid, 0, __thread_proxy<ret_type, args_types...>, &fn);` The `&fn` will get you in deep trouble.

Comment: @dyp For which reason (I don't doubt of it, just want to know why :D). By the way, the tuple solution seems to fix it.

Comment: [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e7dc17793c809a4) a **very** basic solution.

Comment: The problem of `&fn` is that you're passing a pointer to (the address of) a *local* function parameter (a pointer to a function pointer).

Comment: Or you can type-erase via a lambda o.O http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6c607514601b013

Comment: @dyp So much things to study on, thanks a lot. I tried so many things, but never been able to make it work. It will allow me to have more ideas of how to use templates and `auto`